# Tor browser update download and anti-virus software

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

When I download a Tor Browser update, I get a warning from Norton File Insight saying I should not trust this download because there is no history and only 5 users in the "Norton Community".  Am I to assume that Symantic is keeping track of who is downloading Tor?  When I download anything does Norton 360 report this download back to Symantic, and who has access to that information?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, antivirus software is notorious for spying on its users to do its job. It will also often upload suspected malware for further analysis, or report back identified threats.